# Are answer downvotes free?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, down-votes

I downvoted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94138) earlier and did not lose rep for it. I've also downvoted other answers and removed them to test. I don't seem to lose rep on answer downvotes. Is this a bug or by design?

**EDIT**

I have also tried downvoting non Community Wiki answers and I am still not losing rep? Is this to do with 5 minute window?

Comment: I get a 404 error on that link. Also answer down-votes are only free if the answer is Community Wiki.

Comment: @ChrisF It used `posts/#`, which doesn't work, so I changed it to `questions/#`, which will redirect to the answer since it's specifying an answer ID and not a question ID.

Comment: If you're retracting the downvote, then you're not going to lose reputation, if that's what's happening. I tested a non-CW answer earlier, I had the -1 up until I retracted it.

Comment: @Grace No. I'm checking rep before I retract.

Comment: Try downvoting my answer below, see if you lose reputation for it.

Comment: Never mind. I did lose rep but had to refresh first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, answer downvotes are not free. Only question downvotes.

That answer is Community Wiki, which provide no reputation change for both voters and the poster. As such, you can downvote those for free.

On testing a non-Community Wiki answer, I still lose reputation. So the rule still works as prescribed. You should make sure to refresh the page. ♪

[Read up here for more information on Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: Confirmed: Downvoting this, I lost a point of rep. (Edit and I'll reverse that. Add some spaces or something. :)